# getting an error in flutter when trying to call function in TypeAheadField suggestionsCallback field

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, widget

Calling the API here and wants to call users() function in TypeAheadField below is my code:

```
 static Future<List<UserLogin>> users() async {
    final response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse('http://3.108.194.111:8080/AtdochubJ-3/user/'));
    // print('email+++ ${email}');
    // print('password ${password}');
    //print(fromJson(json)).toList());
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('response++++ $response');

      final parsed = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

      return parsed.map<UserLogin>((json) => UserLogin.fromJson(json)).toList();

    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load Document');
    }
  }
```

And I am calling function like this here:

```
SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.06,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                child: TypeAheadField<UserLogin>(
                  hideSuggestionsOnKeyboardHide: true,
                  textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0.05),

                      fillColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 246, 252),
                      suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.close,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(137, 221, 221, 221),
                          size: 20,
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          docTitleController.clear();
                          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                        },
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          ),
                      hintText: 'Appointment Executive ',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                    ),
                    controller: this.docTitleController,
                  ),
                  suggestionsCallback: LoginController.users,
                  itemBuilder: (context, UserLogin Allusers) {
                    final user = Allusers;

                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(user.userName),
                    );
                  },
                  noItemsFoundBuilder: (context) => Container(
                    height: 50,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'No Staff Found.',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onSuggestionSelected: (UserLogin? AllUsers) {
                    final user = AllUsers!;
                    this.aptExecutiveController.text = user.userName;


                    setState(() {
                      this.staff_Id = user.userId;
                    });

                    
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

on line suggestionsCallback: LoginController.users,
I am facing below issue:
The argument type 'Future<List> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<Iterable> Function(String)'.

Answer (score 0):

please change the code to this.

```
suggestionsCallback: (pattern)async {
              return await LoginController.users();
            },
```